# Codemirror holding extra key

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm using Codemirror's `extraKeys` where I defined <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> to send query to my database. The problem is when a user holds these two buttons it's constantly sending that query to the database.

Is there a way fix this?